# I can't connect from Mac when I change the default shell to bash on Windows 11 SSH

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, mac

I started an OpenSSH server on Windows and connected from a Mac terminal.

I was able to connect when the default shell was cmd.exe, PowerShell, or GitBash, but not when I changed to bash.

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

The following is the error I got when connecting via SSH from a Mac.

```
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/masamoto/.ssh/known_hosts for 192.168.68.74 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching /Users/masamoto/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 192.168.68.74 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file /Users/masamoto/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TERMINAL_VERSION = "3.4.20"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8"
debug1: channel 0: setting env LC_TERMINAL = "iTerm2"
debug1: client_global_hostkeys_private_confirm: server used untrusted RSA signature algorithm ssh-rsa for key 0, disregarding
debug1: update_known_hosts: known hosts file /Users/masamoto/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
ファイルにアクセスできません。(※ This message is displayed in Japanese. It means "Cannot access file.)
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to 192.168.68.74 closed.
Transferred: sent 4988, received 3760 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 63995.5, received 48240.4
debug1: Exit status 0
```

I think it seems that I cannot access "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe".

I was able to start bash by opening a PowerShell terminal on the Windows and executing "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe". However, after setting the default OpenSSH terminal to PowerShell and connecting by ssh from a Mac, running "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" gives me "Cannot access file" displayed and cannot be executed. (This message was displayed in Japanese and translated into English, so it may differ from the actual message.)

The user connecting via SSH belongs to the Administrators group, the same as a user logging in on Windows.

I tried copying "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" to the user folder and setting it as the default shell, but the result was the same.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what happens when you run `bash.exe` directly on the windows machine

Comment: After the message "Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS ...", the command prompt like `masamoto@WindowsPC:/mnt/c/Users/miyat$` will appear and bash commands can be executed.

Comment: so, you're trying to SSH into windows machine, and execute the WSL shell?

Comment: Yes. I just noticed that when I connect via SSH from a Mac, I can't even run the wsl command. If I type `wsl -l`, I get a message saying "Cannot access file".